# Kafka: Why is the Sink Connector start() method called twice?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm starting worker in distributed mode and using REST API to start ONE connector, I have a print statement in the start() of HdfsSinkConnector class:

```
 @Override
 public void start(Map<String, String> props) throws ConnectException {
     System.out.println("In connector start method()");
```

}

I see that this method is being called twice for the same connector and this is going to cause problems because I need to include custom initializations in this start() method and I wouldn't want them being initialized twice.

1) When is start() method called?

2) Why is it being called TWICE though I'm starting only one connector and I've checked that there is no other connector running in the same worker service?

3) How do I make sure that this start() method is called only once per connector?

Comment: Where are you seeing it called twice?

Comment: @cricket_007 In the worker logs

Comment: Okay, and what kinds of custom things are you trying to do that aren't idempotent?

Comment: For example, I have a custom library that is writing a total # of records to another kafka topic and with start() being called twice, I see the total # being multiplied.

Comment: I feel like that logic should be placed in the RecordWriter implementations, where it actually flushes the file to disk. Have you tried to setup a debugger in the Connect source code? I personally don't know why it would be called more than once unless you are using multiple tasks in the config

Comment: I have 12 tasks in tasks.max but that would still result in just one connector and 12 tasks right?

Comment: Right, but multiple threads need "started". 12 tasks because you have at least 12 partitions in the topic, I assume... As stated, I'm not sure. And I would also suggest trying another connector to see if you can find the same behavior

Comment: Correct, we have 12 partitions. Also, I see this multiple times "[INFO] 2018-09-26 05:44:53,860 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker startConnector - Instantiated connector pr-car with version 4.0.0 of type class io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector"  So looks like the connector is being instantiated twice

Comment: I also want to add that I don't see this happening when I start the same connector is standalone mode